# Objective-C reflection; passing parameter to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection, selector

I need to use reflection/introspection in objective c. I am able to create instance by writing;

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIView") alloc]init];
```

At this point, i also want it to set its frame.

I have written the code piece below, but it does not compile.

```
SEL method2 = NSSelectorFromString(@"setFrame:");
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
NSValue * value = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
[object performSelector:method2 withObject:value];
```

How can i pass the parameter to setFrame or setBackgroundColor method of an object.

Could you please help me to figure it out?

Thanks in advance

edit

i have found the solution i want,

there is a method called CGRectFromString(NSString*)

it solved my problem.

i am able to set the frame of a view with the code below

```
SEL method2 = NSSelectorFromString(@"setFrame:");

if([object respondsToSelector:method2])
{
    [object setFrame:CGRectFromString(@"{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}")];
}
```

Comment: Which line does not compile? What error message do you get?

Comment: Not having any problem in my side

Comment: May be you are having the problem in `setFrame:` method

Comment: Your code compiles and runs just fine. Please explain your problem and  show your error message. - At present, people are just guessing ...

Comment: actually, i am mistaken, my code compiles but, does not affect

Comment: If you doesn't use variables inside `NSClassFromString` and `NSSelectorFromString` what's the problem to write:`UIView* object = [UIView alloc]init];` and `[object setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);`?

Comment: if you already know you want to use `setFrame:` since it's hard-coded in the direct call, why not use `@selector(setFrame:)` instead of having to look it up using `NSSelectorFromString`?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, in my opinion it is more clear and straightforward. Note the the `respondsToSelector` is just to avoid crashing by sending a method to an object that does not implement it (in your question you are not checking that, so maybe is not needed in your case).

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIView") alloc]init];

if(object respondsToSelector:@selector(setFrame:)){
  [object setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
}
```

Comment: @Basheer_CAD not in this case

Comment: you are not getting any warnings ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD you can send any method to an object (id) if the method is not there the app will crash, that is why you have to protect it with respondsToSelector. But the code compiles perfectly fine without warnings.

Comment: ok, just change the @selector() with NSSelectorFromString(@"setFrame:") to match the question :)

Comment: if you already know you want to use `setFrame:` since it's hard-coded in the direct call, why not use `@selector(setFrame:)`?